# как в делфи менять цвет обычной кнопки?

Tags: delphi

помню что  через canvas менять цвет,но не знаю как

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread814162.html

Comment: обычной кнопки TButton - никак, её отрисовка возложена на систему.

Comment: Задавался похожим вопросом, вот что выяснил - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301498/out-of-the-box-flat-borderless-button

Comment: есть сторонняя библиотека с  TJvColorButton (https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvColorButton)